# sum from both mysql table columns

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have two mysql tables:

```
table: loan
--------------------------------------------------------
 id | advance_id | loan_amount | deposit_amount | date
--------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 22556678 | 5000 | 0 | 2015-02-06
 2 | 22556678 | 5000 | 0 | 2015-02-07
--------------------------------------------------------

table: advance
--------------------------------------------------------
id | advance_id | advance_amount | purpose | date
--------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 22556678 | 20000 | purchase | 2015-01-30
 2 | 22556678 | 10000 | purchase | 2015-01-31
```

I want to get sum of 'loan_amount' from table: loan and sum of 'advance_amount' from table: advance in one mysql query joined by INNER JOIN.

How to get the sum from columns of two tables?

```
SELECT 
  a.advance_id,
  SUM(a.advance_amount) AS adv_amount,
  a.purpose,
  a.date,
  SUM(l.loan_amount) AS loan_amount 
FROM
  advance AS a 
  INNER JOIN loan AS l 
    ON a.advance_id = l.advance_id 
GROUP BY a.advance_id 
HAVING SUM(l.loan_amount) - SUM(l.deposit_amount) > 0
```

Comment: SELECT a.advance_id, sum(a.advance_amount) as adv_amount, a.purpose, a.date, sum(l.loan_amount) as loan_amount FROM advance as a INNER JOIN loan as l ON a.advance_id=l.advance_id GROUP BY a.advance_id HAVING sum(l.loan_amount)-sum(l.deposit_amount)>0

Comment: But it is making loan_amount double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can rewrite your query as

```
SELECT 
  a.advance_id,
  SUM(a.advance_amount) AS adv_amount,
  a.purpose,
  a.date,
  l.loan_amount 
FROM
  advance AS a 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT advance_id,SUM(deposit_amount) AS loan_amount
    FROM loan
    GROUP BY advance_id
    HAVING SUM(loan_amount) - SUM(deposit_amount) > 0 
  )  AS l USING(advance_id)
GROUP BY a.advance_id
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d19d/1)